# How to pass Enum from view to model ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

the controller code looks like

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    public enum EmployeeType
    {
        RecruitmentOffice,
        ResearchInstitute
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int id, EmployeeType type)
    {            
        switch (type)
        {
            case EmployeeType.RecruitmentOffice:
                // load repository
                // load domain object
                // load view specific to recruitment office
                break;
            case EmployeeType.ResearchInstitute:
                // load repository
                // load domain object
                // load view specific to recruitment office
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

now i want that how to generate `form action method` which will point to `Details` action method and pass the enum value like `EmployeeType.RecruitmentOffice or EmployeeType.ResearchInstitute`

and again when i will call that action method by `jquery` then how could i pass parameter `for id & EmployeeType`.

please discuss with sample code. thanks

Comment: just tell me how the url would look like for details action method? how to pass value for enum from view to action method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What about sending as `string` and convert to enum

```
public ActionResult Details(int id, string type)
{ 
EmployeeType empType= (EmployeeType) Enum.Parse(
                                          typeof(EmployeeType), type, true );
}
```

or do write the custom model binder.

***Note:*** Request params are string

Comment: In later versions, it looks like ASP.NET will do the string parsing for you, so you can use the enum directly in the action parameters.

Answer (score 2):

This is also pretty cool:

```
[Flags]
public enum PersonRole { User, Student, Instructor };
```

then from your razor view:

```
<button onclick="onclickDeleteRole('@(PersonRoleEnum.User|PersonRoleEnum.Student)')">
```

and in your javascript:

```
function onclickDeleteRole(role) {
    var personId = $('#SelectedPersonId').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: window.getUrl('Person/DeletePersonRole'),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            personId: personId,
            roles: role
        },
        success: function (json) {
            alert('success!')
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
            alert('error')
        }
    });
}
```

and your controller action:

```
public JsonResult DeletePersonRole(int personId, PersonRoleEnum roles)
{
    // do business logic here...
    // roles will now have value PersonRoleEnum.User|PersonRoleEnum.Student
    // and you can use roles.HasFlag(PersonRoleEnum.User) to check if that flag is set

    return Json(new {Result = "OK"});
}
```

EDIT: for readability, you can always use strings in javascript, and MVC will parse those for you, e.g.

```
$.ajax({
        url: window.getUrl('Person/DeletePersonRole'),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            personId: 1,
            roles: 'Student'
        },
        success: function (json) {
            alert('success!')
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
            alert('error')
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass an enum value in your form, it will show up as an int in you controller. I think you have 2 ways to handle this :

- make the `type` parameter an int, then cast it to your enum in your action
- make a specific model binder that looks for an input called `type` and tries to cast it before getting into your action.

Some links, with sample code, may help you :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/551576/ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-and-Data-Annotation

Comment: just tell me how the url would look like for details action method? how to pass value for enum from view to action method?

Answer (score 1):

If your enum is defined like this:

```
public enum EmployeeType {
    RecruitmentOffice, //value = 0
    ResearchInstitute //value = 1
}
```

In your View (*.cshtml) you can pass enum value like this:

```
var enumVal = 0; @* RecruitmentOffice *@
$.ajax({
    url: '@(Url.Action("Details", "Employee"))',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        id: employeeId ,
        type: enumVal
    }
    success: function (result) {
       @* Handle success *@
    }
}
```

Where the **enumVal** is the **Enum Value you need**. And don't forget to decorate your **Details** action method with **[HttPost]**.