# error using enum for displaying data

Tags: c#, ajax, enums

The view appears for a second and then the following error gets thrown-

**The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'sortField' of non-nullable type 'Project.Enumerators.SortResultEnum' for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult] Details(Project.Enumerators.SortResultEnum, System.Web.Helpers.SortDirection, System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])' in 'Project.Controllers.SearchController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters**

I have a form which is making an ajax call and later ajax call forwards it to controller.

Ajax call:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#SearchForm', function () {
var $form = $(this);
var $searchString = $("#SearchString").val();
var $sortField = $form.attr("data-sortOrder");
var $sortDirection = $form.attr("data-sortDirection");

SortResults($sortField, $sortDirection, $searchString);
});
```

Form:

```
 <form id="SearchForm" action="@Url.Action("Details", "Search")" method="get" data-ajax="true" data-sortOrder="@SortResultEnum.ClientName" data-sortDirection="@SortDirection.Ascending">

   @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentSearchString as string, new { id = "SearchString", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "" })
  <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="search-btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
   </span>

        </form>
```

Controller Action is like

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(SortResultEnum sortField,SortDirection sortDirection, string searchString,  int? page)
 {
     //code to call service and get result is here
    // partial view is being used to display data

}
```

Can someone please help me with this error. Thanks.

Comment: The error message is telling you that your action is not receiving a value for tis `sortField` parameter. Debug your code to see why.  Presumably `$form.attr("data-sortOrder")` doesn't produce a valid value.  If it does, that value must be being lost somewhere. Debug to find out where. By the way, why are you prefixing your variables with `$`?

Comment: You are passing enum value to controller `sortField`, not complete enum. You must replace `SortResultEnum sortField` to `string sortField`. You controller action method should have following parameters `public async Task<ActionResult> Details(string sortField, string sortDirection, string searchString,  int? page)`

Comment: @mmushtaq, that's not correct. The parameter is supposed to receive a value of type `SortResultEnum`, so it should be declared as that type. The problem is that no such value is being passed.

Comment: The correct value is being received in $form.attr("data-sortOrder"). My form appears for a second and then gets lost and the error appears. I have checked the model being passed in PartialView has all the correct values

Comment: @jmcilhinney I wonder how OP can pass `Enum` type parameter to controller. As suggested in following [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043445/how-to-pass-enum-from-view-to-model-asp-net-mvc), enum values should be passed as `int` or `string` and convert these values to enum types in controller.

Comment: @mmushtaq-the error remains same, I tried using string in place of SortResultEnum. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Tina did you convert string value to enum type in controller? Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20046585/3814721)

Comment: used this- SortResultEnum sortField1 =
                (SortResultEnum ) Enum.Parse(typeof(SortResultEnum ), sortField, true); Got the result but same thing happened and I got the error

Comment: although it will not solve your problem but will be easy to debug.  First don't make you action `async` as of now and within action method see if you are getting all the correct values.  and if if you are getting, then there is not error in above code. its some where else ..

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed "" in data-sortOrder.
Try this.

```
  data-sortOrder="@SortResultEnum.ClientName"
```

Comment: What difference will it make? I am getting the right value in the model that I am passing to PartialView. The partialView appears for a second and then gets disappeared and the error message appears

Comment: ReplaceResults(response);
Never used or seen this function before. Is it default function or your own???

Comment: I just made it.